# I don't have a Minecraft save

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was in a Minecraft command block and I accidently pressed `x`.

Does that have a save or not because I was in the command block for about 3 mins, and I don't know what to expect when I log on.

Answer (score 1):

Your world should be saved, however, the contents of the command block will not be. Changes to command blocks aren't saved until you press "done".

So don't be afraid, your save hasn't corrupted itself just because you hit X. It's fine. Your command block work is gone, but everything else should be saved.